# How to index a street address column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a Location table with a street address column.  My app provides a search mechanism that queries locations with this column and I am trying to speed up the queries.  The db has a little over 2 million records and I just thought I'd put out this question to see what people have done.  I'm sure I'm not the first.  My question is basically this:  given a primary key, address, city, state, zip columns, how should this table be indexed so that queries like the following don't take 10 seconds:

```
`select * from location where loc_address_s like '%blvd%'`
`select * from location where loc_address_s like 'oak' AND loc_city like 'salem'`
```

etc...

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, consider implementing a Fulltext index on loc_address_s. That might do what you'd like.

Comment: Best option is to split the street address into multiple fields. building #, street name, street type, direction, etc... each would be individually indexable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet, if it's at all possible, is to break the address down into its components. This is how the U.S. post office stores addresses as well as many (most?) large address handling companies and agencies. Database design best practices usually include not having a column hold more than one piece of data for a row. Right now you're storing a street number, street direction (N for "North Main Street" for example), street name, street type, etc.

Once you have everything broken out properly you can index individual columns if you need to do that.

I'm sure that there's a standard out there (a quick search of the ansi.org website didn't give me anything though). Storing addresses is a pretty common thing to have to do.

Also, you can find many address clean-up services and software to break up addresses into these columns if you don't want to go through that effort entirely on your own.

Answer (score 3):

A query that includes a `LIKE` predicate starting with `%` cannot be helped by an index - it will have to do a full table/clustered index scan.

Generally, the solution to problems such as these is full-text indexing. Take a look at [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) for info.

However, I've implemented custom tokenisation and then using regular indexes successfully in the past too - for address data. Split the addresses up into words/tokens and store each unique token in a `Token` table. Then have an `Address` table that contains a unique identifier for each address and any other meta-data you want. And, lastly, an `AddressToken` table which has a foreign key to each of the previous tables and a row for each token in each address. You might want to denormalise this approach (possibly via an indexed via) to get even better performance.

Comment: It can use an index but it will resort to an index scan instead of an index seek. reference: http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/jnelson/archive/2007/11/16/108354.aspx

Comment: Actually an index can help, scanning a single column index takes a lot less disk reads than scanning a clustered index

Comment: @Andomar OP wants `SELECT *` so if the number of matching rows is large, a table scan or clustered index scan may be better than non-clustered index scan with bookmark lookups.

Comment: @Daniel: The clauses `LIKE '%text'` and `LIKE 'text%'` **can** make use of indexes. You might be thinking of `LIKE '%text%'` which can't.

Comment: @Yuck - `LIKE '%text'` won't make any more use of an index than `LIKE '%text%'`

Comment: @Tom: So you're right - interesting. I incorrectly remembered reading that in an old issue of SQL Mag. Thanks for the clarification.